# Bootstrap 3 move column to expand row and keep column below it nested with the next column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

By default, I have 3 elements on my page like so:

```
___________________________
|  Element  | Element 2 |
|      1    | Element 3 |
---------------------------
```

What I need to is on a click event, change element 2 to be on top with full width, while keeping element 1 and element 3 together like so:

```
___________________________
|      Element 2         |
| Element  |   Element 3 |
|    1     |             |
---------------------------
```

Also included a few screenshots that may help visualizing it:

Element Layout - Default

[image: Element Layout - Default]

Element Layout - After transition

[image: Element Layout - After transition]

I've tried using push and pull bootstrap classes, which works except the 3rd element is always forced to a new row, under element 1. I've seen other examples where they make the default layout with element 2 and 3 in their own rows, but that doesn't work without a lot of manipulation when changing it to full width.

Here is my current markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <div>Element 2</div>
        <div>Element 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        <div>Element 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have tried moving element 3 to its own column too, but it always ends up as below element 1 with its own row, like when I do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <div>Element 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        <div>Element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <div>Element 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to use jquery to make the moves between elements?

Comment: @TravisActon Yes. One idea I was thinking is just using my own grid system with similar styles and use JQuery to change width/height of all these. But was hoping for an easier solution than making up all of that.

Comment: this seems like the perfect use case for the new css grid layout. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ It's not fully supported on older browsers though so you might not be able to use it. If you want to try, look into the `grid-template-areas` property. You can use your click event to add a class that re-arranges the areas per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about pre-defining a top row and setting width to 12.

In jquery you can add click elements to each and then append them to the top div when clicked. You could also iterate through your click elements on page load to determine/set a data attribute that would allow you to move them back to their original place if clicked again when already on the top row.

https://jsfiddle.net/eobxja1k/5/

HTML SETUP:

```
<div class="row" id="myContainer">
  <div class="col-8 offset-3" id="topRow"></div>
  <div class="col-4" id="bottomRow1">
    <div class="clickMe">Element 2</div>
        <div class="clickMe">Element 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8" id="bottomRow2">
        <div class="clickMe">Element 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
    $('.clickMe').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data-original', $(this).parent().attr('id'));
    });
});

$('.clickMe').click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().attr('id') != 'topRow'){
    $(this).appendTo('#topRow');
  } else {
    $(this).appendTo('#' + $(this).data('original'));
  }
});
```

Css:

```
#topRow {
  color: white;
  color: black;
}

#bottomRow1 {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 25px;
}

#bottomRow2 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  min-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to entertain the new CSS Grid system you can do this relatively easily. This solution uses the `grid-template-areas` property to define areas called `one`, `two`, and `three`. Then on click a class is added to the container element that re-arranges each of these three areas into the "post transition" layout that you specify.

```js
$('html').click(function(){
 $('.container').toggleClass('two-on-top');
})
```

```css
.elem {
 border: grey solid 2px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "one two"
        "one three"
        "one ."
        "one ."
}

.elem1 {
  grid-area:  one;
}

.elem2 {
  grid-area:  two;
}

.elem3 {
  grid-area:  three;
}


.two-on-top {
    grid-template-areas: 
        "two two"
        "one three"
        "one ."
        "one ."
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="elem elem1">
   Elem 1
  </div>
   <div class="elem elem2">
   Elem 2
  </div>
  <div class="elem elem3">
   Elem 3
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand what is happening here check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas